# Erro no deploy django/app no heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, anaconda

Necessito da ajuda de vocês para tentar encontrar o erro no meu deploy, que estou tentando fazer no heroku.

Segue informações do bash:

```
(python3) user@Inspiron-5548:~/opt/anaconda3/envs/python3/Projetos/ecommerce$ heroku logs
(python3) user@Inspiron-5548:~/opt/anaconda3/envs/python3/Projetos/ecommerce$ heroku keys:add ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
Uploading /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub SSH key... done
(python3) user@Inspiron-5548:~/opt/anaconda3/envs/python3/Projetos/ecommerce$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 53, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (48/48), done.
Writing objects: 100% (53/53), 46.43 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 53 (delta 9), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing Python-3.6.1
remote: -----> Installing pip
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        /app/tmp/buildpacks/779a8bbfbbe7e1b715476c0b23fc63a2103b3e4131eda558669aba8fb5e6e05682419376144189b29beb5dee6d7626b4d3385edb0954bffea6c67d8cf622fd51/bin/steps/pip-install: line 7: /app/.heroku/python/bin/pip: No such file or directory
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: ! Push rejected to primeirodjango.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/primeirodjango.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/primeirodjango.git'
```

Segue informações:

requirements.txt

```
dj-database-url==0.4.2
Django==1.11.4
gunicorn==19.7.1
psycopg2==2.7.3
```

runtime.txt

```
python-3.6.1
```

Procfile

```
web: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```

Obs:

1. Primeira vez usando heroku, mas fiz o dever de casa e a comunicação está toda configurada conforme documentação do repositório.
2. Dentro do nosso projeto, escolhemos usar o **Anaconda** por ele ser um pacote python completo. Para iniciar o projeto fiz uma envs dentro do **Anaconda 3**, mas ela ultrapassava seus 1GB de tamanho. Como não tinha conseguido fazer o "deploy" de primeira, acreditei ter sido o tamanho, logo diminui o arquivo "requirements.txt" para libs essenciais.

Comment: Da uma olhada aqui https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-app-configuration. O heroku sugere que use 'gunicorn' como webserver pra Django. Tenta alterar seu procfile usando este webserver. [Mais um link útil](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-gunicorn)

Comment: Obrigado @flaviomeira10, vou verificar agora.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O heroku não suporta o `python 3.6.1`, apenas o **3.6.2**
[Segue o link oficial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes#supported-python-runtimes)

Comment: Essa resposta https://stackoverflow.com/a/44034968/362438 no SO em inglês se refere a versão do Python também. Pelo visto, a que o vic.py está tentando não é mais suportada mesmo e o erro engana bastante.

Answer (score 0):

No teu repositório deves ter alterações que ainda não esta na maquina o que provavelmente leva a esse erro tenta forçar o **push** desta maneira:

`git push -f heroku master`